# Issues with executable: file not found after using chmod to fix permissions

Tags: permissions, chmod, executable

I have downloaded and extracted the Linux binary for the [blackbox PDDL planner](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~kautz/satplan/blackbox/), and I'm trying to get the `blackbox` file to execute. I changed to the directory with the file and tried `./blackbox`, which gave me a permissions error. No big deal, just run `chmod 755 blackbox` to give it executable permissions. But then, when I try `./blackbox` again, I get the following error:

```
bash: ./blackbox: No such file or directory
```

It does the same when I give the command arguments. When I run `ls -l` though, I see the `blackbox` file and it has `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions, so I'm not sure why it's "losing" the file.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot with Windows 7, if that matters.

**EDIT:** I found a [helpful question](https://superuser.com/questions/194254/why-would-an-executable-say-it-doesnt-exist-when-i-try-to-run-it) over on Superuser, which has gotten me partially there. I ran `readelf -l ./blackbox | grep ld-linux` to find what I needed, then did a package content search to find out I needed the `libc6-i386` package. Now I can do the following:

```
user@ubuntu:~/path$ ./blackbox 
./blackbox: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
user@ubuntu:~/path$ ldd blackbox 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77af000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf774f000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf75a4000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77b0000)
```

Comment: Is your system 32 bit or 64 bit? what is the output of commands `file blackbox` and `ldd blackbox`?

Comment: Looks like a 64 bit system. `file blackbox` tells me that the executable is 32 bit, and `ldd blackbox` gives the message `not a dynamic executable`

Comment: @steeldriver I've solved part of the problem. Now I get output from `ldd`, which I've posted in an edit to the question

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the `blackbox` executable was a 32-bit program, and I am running a 64-bit OS. Here's the (somewhat hacky) steps I took to resolve this issue (partially chronicled in [this question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/194254/why-would-an-executable-say-it-doesnt-exist-when-i-try-to-run-it)):

- `uname -m` told me I have a 64-bit OS, but `file blackbox` told me that this exe was 32-bit.
- `ldd blackbox` (strangely) told me that the file was not a dynamic executable, even though I also saw this from `file`. Trying `readelf -l ./blackbox | grep ld-linux` told me `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]`, which was a shared library that I didn't have at that location.
- `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386` to get that library file (found that with a package search on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com)).
- Now `ldd` gave me output, and I was missing `libstdc++.so.6` and `libgcc_s.so.1` (see my edit), so I needed to get these files.
- After a bit more pacakage searching, I found that the `gcc-snapshot` package had the two files I was missing. This is probably a massive hammer for my tiny nail, and there are likely better solutions, but `sudo apt-get install gcc-snapshot` got me the files I needed.
- After running `ldd` again, this resolved the issue with `libgcc_s.so.1`, but `libstdc++.so.6` was still not found. I ended up going to the place where `ldd` found `libgcc_s.so.1` and running `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6` to get a symlink to the recently installed file.

Comment: A less hacky solution would probably be to enable i386 [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) using `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, then update your repositories `sudo apt-get update` after which you could have explicitly installed the `libc6:i386` and `libstdc++6:i386` packages in the normal way